# How to place secure file in rancher storage?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, hdfs, rancher

I build a kafka connect docker image and I use rancher to start the kafka connect cluster.The cluster need to connect kerberos enabled hdfs. So I need to place keytab file into the cluster. I don't want to build my keytab file into the image which I build., because it is important and secure. So I want to use the rancher storage service, But I can not place my keytab into the storage?
my question is : How to manage my secure file in rancher or docker?

Answer (score 3):

base64 encode your keytab and pass that to the container as an environment variable. Create an `entrypoint` script that places the base64 decoded value into your keytab file.

```
export KEYTAB=$(cat /etc/krb5.keytab | base64)
docker run -e KEYTAB my_image
```

In your entrypoint script:

```
printenv KEYTAB | base64 -d > /etc/krb5.keytab
```

Ultimately, manage your keytab the same way you manage all other container secrets - just base64 encode it so that you're managing it as another string and not a file.